# Elassandra: UDT List Match Query- No Results

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, elassandra

I am using Elassandra. In Cassandra, I have a UDT:

```
CREATE TYPE test.entity_attributes (
    attribute_key text,
    attribute_value text
);
```

It is used in table

```
CREATE TABLE test.attributes_test (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    attr list<frozen<entity_attributes>>
)
```

I mapped the `attributes_test` using:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'localhost:9200/attr_index' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "settings": { "keyspace": "test" },
    "mappings": {
        "attributes_test" : {
            "discover":".*"
        }
    }
}'
```

(copied from postman)
It returns the following as mapping:

```
{
    "attr_index": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "attributes_test": {
                "properties": {
                    "attr": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "cql_udt_name": "entity_attributes",
                        "properties": {
                            "attribute_key": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "cql_collection": "singleton"
                            },
                            "attribute_value": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "cql_collection": "singleton"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "cql_collection": "singleton",
                        "cql_partition_key": true,
                        "cql_primary_key_order": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "keyspace": "test",
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "provided_name": "attr_index",
                "creation_date": "1615291749532",
                "number_of_replicas": "0",
                "uuid": "Oua1ACLbRvCATC-kcGPoQg",
                "version": {
                    "created": "6020399"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have in the table:

```
 id | attr
----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2 | [{attribute_key: 'abc', attribute_value: '2'}, {attribute_key: 'def', attribute_value: '1'}]
  1 |                                               [{attribute_key: 'abc', attribute_value: '1'}]
```

The problem now is, when I run the following query, it does not return any result.

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:9200/attr_index/_search' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "attr.attribute_key": "abc"
        }
    }
}'
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html - describes the way to search in nested objects.
How can I search in the list of nested objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake in my query. The correct query would be:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "attr",
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "attr.attribute_key": "abc"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```